# Count query with 3 columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have one database named "Library" with table named "Medien".
Having multiple columns among them i need to query for the following coloumn named as Fname,Mname,Lname and ISBN.

**I want to calculate database total records with ISBN and without ISBN?**

- Fname = First Name of Author
- Mname = Middle Name of Author
- Lname = Last Name of Author

I want to count how many record are for ISBN and how many without ISBN ?

I have execute following command

```
 Select COUNT(ISBN) as Fname FROM  `library`.`MEDIEN` where  Fname = `isbn`;
 Select COUNT(ISBN) as Mname FROM  `library`.`MEDIEN` where  Mname = `isbn`;
 Select COUNT(ISBN) as Lname FROM  `library`.`MEDIEN` where  Lname = `isbn`;
 Select COUNT(ISBN) as NtFname FROM `library`.`MEDIEN`where  Fname != `isbn`;
 Select COUNT(ISBN) as NtMname FROM `library`.`MEDIEN`where  Mname != `isbn`;
 Select COUNT(ISBN) as NtLname FROM `library`.`MEDIEN`where  Lname != `isbn`;
```

I am not sure i execute correct command or not.
Because some ISBN records have Fname,Mname or Fname,Lname or Mname,Lname or Fname , Lname,Mname only respectively.

For example

**First Author**

Fname: asher
Lname: baig

have written 5 books records but two of them with ISBN so

Total output will be ISBN = 2

Desire output will be like this

`ISBN=value and NtISBN=value`

Please kindly help me solving this query

Comment: Please post your schema, sample data, and desired output.

Comment: What is verf1, verf2, verf3? Your question is unclear.

Comment: It is not clear what you want, and it is not clear what trouble you are having.  If you post the following three things, we may be abe to more confidently help you:  `1.` A sample set of data.  `2.` The results your want to get.  `3.` The results you're actually getting, and why there is a problem with them.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably just want to use two queries, with an OR clause.  That will avoid certain rows from being counted twice:

```
Select COUNT(ISBN) as count FROM library.MEDIEN where
 verf1 = 'isbn'
 OR verf2 = 'isbn'
 OR verf3 = 'isbn';
```

And then of course in the inverse:

```
Select COUNT(ISBN) as count FROM library.MEDIEN where verf1 != 'isbn'
   AND verf2 != 'isbn'
   AND verf3 != 'isbn';
```

Comment: ... Except the `verfn` columns are the aliases he's using for the `COUNT()` aggregate (or seem to be), so they may not exist in the original table?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse - Yea valid point.  Though from the statement *"I want to calculate database records with ISBN and without ISBN"*, I think I understand the poster's actual intention.  I'm thinking they're just confused by SQL syntax.  Hopefully they'll clarify, but I think I'll leave my answer up in the off chance it helps.

Comment: @asherbaig - I think you need to post your schema.  Is `ISBN` a column?  Are you looking for distinct `ISBN` values for a specific author?

Comment: There are 4 coloumn one of them is ISBN.No i want to calculate total ISBN number in coloumn ISBN but each isbn number has Fname or Mname or Lname.As total Number of records is 282953 among them how many records has ISBN number and how many doesn't have ISBN records.For exmaple after i execute query it give 72589 record or rows has isbn and 25589 has no isbn number.I hope it is clear.

Comment: Rows with ISBN value would be: `select count(1) from library.MEDIEN where ISDN is not null;`, and records without an ISDN number would be the opposite: `select count(1) from library.MEDIEN where ISDN is null;`

Comment: @Mike Chritensen This query return default value like i said 282953 and with not null 0.I think it is not cleared yet.I execute this query `select count(1) from library.MEDIEN where Fname is not null` it return 282953. which means there are **some records which has no isbn number** how can we find those records.remeber only count is required.

Comment: @asherbaig - I'm not quite sure what you need.  Can you post an example on sqlfiddle.com with your schema and some example data?

Comment: @MikeChristensen I have uploaded my DB in csv format which can be downloaded from here `http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?5twx721gy72vt29` kindly help me find how many ISBN number are out of total number of records.There u can find Verf1,verf2,verf3 respectively for Fname,Mname,Lname.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN (verf1 = 'isbn' OR verf2 = 'isbn' OR verf3 = 'isbn') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) ISBNCount
        SUM (CASE WHEN (verf1 = 'isbn' OR verf2 = 'isbn' OR verf3 = 'isbn') THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ) NtISBNC 
         FROM library.MEDIEN
```